# Sumar valores a partir de cierto número

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que a partir de 30 kilómetros se sume 0.45 céntimos al kilómetro de más. Es decir, si la distancia es 30 kilómetros, sería envío gratis; y si la distancia es 35km, el coste del envío sería 5 * 0.45 = 2.25€.

No se como añadirlo os dejo el código que intento:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Su distancia es...
    <script language="JavaScript">
      var distancia = prompt("Distancia desde la tienda a su hogar");
      document.write( distancia );
      if (distancia > 30) { 

        distancia + 0.45;

      } else { 

        document.write("Envio y Montaje gratis") 

      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es superior a 30 km, debes restar 30 de la distancia y multiplicar el resultado por 0.45:

```
if (distancia > 30) { 
    coste = (distancia - 30) * 0.45;
    document.write("Te va a costar " + coste.toFixed(2) + "€");
} else { 
    document.write("Envio y Montaje gratis") 
}
```

Comment: Cierto es asi muchas gracias =) no habia caido que tonto

Comment: En tal caso, márcala como la respuesta correcta @RafaAlvarez-OssorioMartin

Answer (score 0):

Te estas olvidando la asignación al momento de sumar. Debes modificar la siguiente linea:

```
    distancia + 0.45;
```

por esta:

```
    distancia += 0.45;  //es el equivalente a: distancia = distancia + 0.45;
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Gracias lo he cambiado pero ahora me suma por ejemplo 35+0.45 = 350.45. Yo lo que queria que me sumara de los 35 el 5+0.45 la diferencia